# Break up a string literal over multiple lines

Tags: java, string, string.format

Is there a way to break up a line of code so that it is read as continuous despite being on a new line in java?

```
public String toString() {

  return String.format("BankAccount[owner: %s, balance: %2$.2f,\
    interest rate: %3$.2f,", myCustomerName, myAccountBalance, myIntrestRate);
  }
```

The code above when I do this all on one line everything works dandy but when I try to do this on multiple lines it doesn't work.

In python I know you use a \ to start typing on a new line but print as one line when executed.

A Example in Python to clarify. In python this will print on one line using 
a backslash or ():

```
print('Oh, youre sure to do that, said the Cat,\
 if you only walk long enough.')
```

the User would see this as:

```
Oh, youre sure to do that, said the Cat, if you only walk long enough.
```

Is there similar ways to do this in java?? Thank you!

Comment: Nope, no way to do that in Java.  The best you can do is concatenate with `+` across a line.

Comment: Could you still String.format() it or would you have to do that for every line?

Comment: if you need a new line `concat` the String with `/n` in the end.

Comment: You can't have multi-line _string literals._  You can still `String.format` if the format is concatenated between multiple lines.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman you get a single `String` literal in the class file as a result of a `String` constant expression. That's effectively a multi-line `String` literal, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Rajith Pemabandu, "`concat` the String with `/n`" will not embed a newline in the `String`. That advice is incorrect.

Comment: @LewBloch, no, I wouldn't agree.  That term usually refers to how it appears in the source as it does in Python, not that the string contains newlines.

Comment: I didn't say anything about a string containing newlines, that was the other guy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Break up the string on the new line using `+` operator works.

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("BankAccount[owner: %s, balance: "
            + "%2$.2f, interest rate:"
            + " %3$.2f]", 
            myCustomerName, 
            myAccountBalance, myIntrestRate);
}
```

Sample Output: `BankAccount[owner: TestUser, balance: 100.57, interest rate: 12.50]`

Comment: Because the multi-line string addition involving only `String` literals and constants is stored as a single literal in the class file, it accomplishes precisely what's being asked for. Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following Java's coding conventions:

```
public String toString() 
{
    return String.format("BankAccount[owner: %s, balance: %2$.2f",
                         + "interest rate: %3$.2f", 
                         myCustomerName, 
                         myAccountBalance, 
                         myIntrestRate);
}
```

Always have the concatenation operator at the beginning of the new line for readability.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-136091.html#248

Hope this helps!

Brady